# By industry practices, should I check internet reachability before making API call or during API call in Alamofire

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire

I just started doing networking through Alamofire, and I am a newbie when it comes to Networking

I am working on response validations in Alamofire Api call, 
So By industry practices Is it better to **check the internet reachability before api request or handling it by the error code that alamofire receives!**

I've read that **checking internet connection before making internet call causes application overhead**

```
{
   let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60      
        manager.request("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/")
          .validate()
          .responseJSON {
            response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
               //  code

                }

            case .failure(let error):
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    print("Request call timed Out !!")
                    self.displayText?.text = "Request call timed Out !!"

                } else if error._code == -1009{
                    print(" You Sir are not Connected to the Internet !!")
                    self.displayText?.text = "You Sir are not Connected to the Internet !!"

                } else if error._code == -1003 {
                    print(" \t bruh, \n Atleast provide a Valid URL ")
                    self.displayText?.text = "bruh,Atleast provide a Valid URL "
                }
                else {
                    print("Meh, Some Kind of error with errorCode: \(error._code) !!")
                    self.displayText?.text = "Meh, Some Kind of error with errorCode: \(error._code) !!"
               }

            }

        }
```

Comment: In my case, I won't check reachability before doing a request unless it have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not check for internet connectivity before making a call. Apple specifically recommended against this. Reachability should only be used after a request failure in case you want to automatically retry requests when the connection is back online.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Internet is available {
//Make rest calls.
}else{
// Return cached response.
}
```

Its upto you, First checking the internet saves computing resources and request creation and api call.

Also gives the option to return the cached data if have.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is up to you and your product specific requirements. It is a good practice however to display some kind of hint to the user when he's trying to reach to the internet while it's unavailable, without displaying any loading indicators and making him to wait. My advice is to not check internet reachability before making any calls, but listen to network reachability changes through Alamofire's `NetworkReachabilityManager` class and make appropriate changes to your UI (e.g. disable network-related buttons when internet is gone, etc.).